# How to ignore duplicate keys while parsing json using gson?

Tags: json, duplicates, gson

I am getting a a duplicate key exception while parsing JSON response containing timestamps as keys using GSON. It gives the following error:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: duplicate key: 1463048935
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:186)
>           at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:141)

How do I make it ignore the duplicate entries, and just parse it to a map with any one from the duplicate entries?

Comment: By avoiding duplicate keys...

Comment: It is the response from an HBase database and there is no way the data can be edited.

Comment: Do you know anything about the data? For instance, the name of the duplicate key?

Comment: the duplicate key exception comes up when there is more than one record  for a timestamp(timestamp is the key here)

Comment: Is the problem occurring only when the timestamp is duplicated? If so, then the problem is solvable. More generally, if you have a finite set of keys which might be duplicated, then the problem is solvable.

Answer (score 2):

**Hackerman solution, tested and working using GSON v2.8.5, but use at your own risk! Whenever you update GSON to a new version, make sure to check whether this is still working!**

Basically, you can use the fact that the generic ObjectTypeAdapter ignores duplicates as seen [here](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/647#issuecomment-106887221):

> Looks like MapTypeAdapterFactory checks for duplicate

```
  V replaced = map.put(key, value);
  if (replaced != null) {
    throw new JsonSyntaxException("duplicate key: " + key);
  }
```

> however ObjectTypeAdapter does not

```
case BEGIN_OBJECT:
  Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedTreeMap<String, Object>();
  in.beginObject();
  while (in.hasNext()) {
    map.put(in.nextName(), read(in));
  }
  in.endObject();
  return map;
```

What you can do now is trying to deserialize using `fromJson` as usual, but catch the "duplicate key" exception, deserialize as a generic Object, which will ignore duplicates, serialize it again, which will result in a JSON string without duplicate keys, and finally deserialize using the correct type it's actually meant to be.

Here is a Kotlin code example:

```
fun <T> String.deserialize(gson: Gson, typeToken: TypeToken<T>): T {
    val type = typeToken.type
    return try {
        gson.fromJson<T>(this, type)
    } catch (e: JsonSyntaxException) {
        if (e.message?.contains("duplicate key") == true) {
            gson.toJson(deserialize(gson, object : TypeToken<Any>() {})).deserialize(gson, typeToken)
        } else {
            throw e
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, this adds (potentially heavy) overhead by requiring 2 deserializations and an additional serialization, but currently I don't see any other way to do this. If Google decides to add an option for a built-in way to ignore duplicates, as suggested [here](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/647#issuecomment-270605299), better switch to that.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't use Kotlin (as answered before), so I adjusted it to Java
It could be achieved by registering the type adder:

```
   @Test
    void testDuplicatesIgnored() {
        String json = "{\"key\": \"value\", \"key\": \"value2\"}";

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Map.class, new JsonDeserializer<Map<String, Object>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, Object> deserialize(JsonElement json1, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
                        return new Gson().fromJson(json1, typeOfT);
                    }
                })
                .create();

        Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType();

        Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(json, mapType);
        System.out.println("map = " + map); // map = {key=value2}

        assertThat(map).hasSize(1);
        assertThat(map.get("key")).isEqualTo("value2");
    }
```

This way all the mappings to `Map.class` will go through your deserializer code
Yea, looks like a dirty hack, but it works

Another way is to register type adder for your custom type to make the deserializer being called only where you need it:

````
    @Test
    void testDuplicatesIgnored() {
        String json = "{\"key\": \"value\", \"key\": \"value2\"}";

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(MapIgnoringDuplicatesContainer.class, new JsonDeserializer<MapIgnoringDuplicatesContainer>() {
                    @Override
                    public MapIgnoringDuplicatesContainer deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
                        Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType();
                        return new MapIgnoringDuplicatesContainer(new Gson().fromJson(json, mapType));
                    }
                })
                .create();

        Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(json, MapIgnoringDuplicatesContainer.class).getMap();
        System.out.println("map = " + map); // map = {key=value2}

        assertThat(map).hasSize(1);
        assertThat(map.get("key")).isEqualTo("value2");
    }

    private class MapIgnoringDuplicatesContainer {

        private Map<String, Object> map;

        public MapIgnoringDuplicatesContainer(Map<String, Object> map) {
            this.map = map;
        }

        public Map<String, Object> getMap() {
            return map;
        }
    }
    ```
````